# Value prediction using LSTM logits

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am looking at [this](https://github.com/lucko515/tesla-stocks-prediction) LSTM example. After training the network, getting multiple predictions using the same input batch, gives different results.

```
for z in range(3):
  o = session.run([model.logits], feed_dict={model.inputs:X_test[0:0+batch_size]})
  print(o)
```

For example, the first predicted value is `-0.24326998, -0.23387843, -0.22564721`.
Given the final logits, shouldn't be they fixed and give a fixed prediction? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the definition of this function:

```
def LSTM_cell(hidden_layer_size, batch_size,number_of_layers, dropout=True, dropout_rate=0.8):
    # ...
    if dropout:
        layer = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(layer, output_keep_prob=dropout_rate)
```

it applies dropout function to the output of each LSTM cell, [tf.nn.dropout()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) and [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/DropoutWrapper) randomly set some percentage of tensor elements to zero, you can check the links for more details. According to the definition of LSTM_cell(), every time you call

```
o = session.run([model.logits], feed_dict={model.inputs:X_test[0:0+batch_size]})
```

each output neuron of each LSTM cell in your model is randomly set to zero with probability 1 - 0.8 = 0.2 = 20%. Therefore your model is stochastic and you get different results even when running the model against the same inputs. 
Dropout is a regularization method useful when training the neural networks, it is useless (and perhaps counter-intuitive) to apply it during the validation and testing mode. I don't want to call the code you mentioned incorrect, but typically one would implement the dropout using a placeholder like this:

```
def LSTM_cell(hidden_layer_size, batch_size,number_of_layers,  dropout_rate):
    # ...
    layer = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_layer_size)
    layer = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(layer, output_keep_prob=dropout_rate)

class StockPredictionRNN(object):
    def __init__(...)
    # ...
    self.dropout_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    cell, init_state = LSTM_cell(hidden_layer_size, batch_size, number_of_layers, self.dropout_placeholder)
```

Set the dropout rate to, for instance, 0.8 during training phase:

```
for i in range(epochs):
    # ...
    o, c, _ = session.run([model.logits, model.loss, model.opt], feed_dict={model.inputs:X_batch, model.targets:y_batch, model.dropout_placeholder: 0.8})
```

Disable dropout by setting dropout rate to 1.0 during testing phase:

```
o = session.run([model.logits], feed_dict={model.inputs:X_test[i:i+batch_size], model.dropout_placeholder: 1.0})
```

For more information about dropout, please check [the original paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a.old/srivastava14a.pdf).